# What is the use of inject reducer and inject saga in react redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have go through some code but i didn't get the working of this inject saga and reducers,
please explain the working of below code

```
const withReducer= injectReducer({key:'',reducer})
const withSaga= injectSaga({key:'',saga})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to code splitting of components to load the piece of code either based on route or action. You can inject the reducer and saga only when they are needed instead of initializing everything on startup.

The above line of code is to inject the reducer that you would like to inject.

Here is a detailed post explaining the use case of this.
https://manukyan.dev/posts/2019-04-15-code-splitting-for-redux-and-optional-redux-saga/